Arduino ESP32 Date and Time from configTime &timeinfo. How do I get this into a variable?
I have an ESP32 that I want to use to capture some data from sensors and I am going to store the data on the cloud for interrogation elsewhere.  I'm using the Arduino IDE.
One of the data items that I want to capture is the date and time when the readings were taken.
I have found getting this is reasonably easy and many places on the web have examples to do this (all pretty similar).
I am using the following within my code:
...

// DateTime processing
const char* ntpServer = "pool.ntp.org";
const long  gmtOffset_sec = 0;
const int   daylightOffset_sec = 3600;

String dateL = "Null";

void getLocalDateTime(){
  struct tm timeinfo;
  if(!getLocalTime(&timeinfo)){
    Serial.println("Failed to obtain time");
    return;
  }
  dateL = (&timeinfo, "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S");
  Serial.println(dateL);
  Serial.println(&timeinfo, "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S");
}

void setup(){
...
}


void loop(){
  ...
  getLocalDateTime();
 ...
}


The output I get is as follows
%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S
20240504 11:23:30

The ... is just other code that is not relevant here.
This is just experimental code where I am trying to get a date and time into my dateL variable so that I can just add this to my data when I write it to the cloud.
Every example that I find of this always uses the same syntax and simply writes it with println I can't find examples of storing this.  Since this must be a string to print (??) then I struggle to understand why this isn't working.   It prints the date time fine but if I use the same syntax to put this into a data item it is just storing the mask syntax for the date and time I am using.
I'm a newbie to Arduino / C++ so be gentle.

Essentially your question is 'how do I print to a string?' I know the C++ answer to this but you are using the Arduino specific 'String' class. I afraid I don't know the answer for that. But maybe you can google how to print to a string arduino style.

You seem to have a misunderstanding of what this code does dateL = (&timeinfo, "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S");. That's an example of C++'s comma operator, whose effect is to evaluate and discard the left hand side, following by evaluating and returning the right hand side. So this code is exactly the same as dateL = "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S";. which explains the results you see.

I suggest you research the strftime function. This is used to print time to a C string.

Delete dateL = (&timeinfo, "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"); and Serial.println(dateL);.

Thanks for the comments.  I think I have found a solution.
Defining my original dateL as char:
    char dateL[80];

Then using the following code in getLocalDateTime instead:
void getLocalDateTime(){

  time_t rawtime; 
  struct tm* timeinfo; 
  time(&rawtime); 

  timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime); 
  //char buffer[80];

  strftime(dateL, 80, "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S",timeinfo); 
}


This now updates the value of dateL whenever I call it.
